# ChannelRelativeUrl is undefinded in MS Graph API context

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

We are building a Microsoft Teams Tab app.
After User login, our app fetch the context info by the following way.

```
  microsoftTeams.getContext((context: microsoftTeams.Context) => {
    dispatch(getContextCallback({ context }))
  })
```

and the context is like the following

```
{
appIconPosition: ...
appLaunchId: "..."
appSessionId: "..."
channelId: "..."
channelName: "..."
channelRelativeUrl: "..." <- **sometime it is undefined**
channelType: "..."
chatId: "..."
defaultOneNoteSectionId: "..."
entityId: "..."
frameContext: "..."
groupId: "..."
hostClientType: "..."
isFullScreen: ...
isMultiWindow: ...
isTeamArchived: ...
jsonTabUrl: "..."
locale: "..."
loginHint: "..."
meetingId: "..."
parentMessageId: "..."
ringId: "..."
sessionId: "..."
sourceOrigin: ...
subEntityId: "..."
teamId: "..."
teamName: "..."
teamSiteDomain: "..."
teamSiteId: "..."
teamSitePath: "..."
teamSiteUrl: "..."
teamTemplateId: "..."
teamType: ...
tenantSKU: "..."
theme: "..."
tid: "..."
upn: "..."
userClickTime: ...
userFileOpenPreference: ...
userLicenseType: ...
userObjectId: ...
userPrincipalName: ...
userTeamRole: ...
}
```

We are taking usage of channelRelativeUrl property to get the file folder connected with the channel. But from our error log, we found sometimes channelRelativeUrl is undefined?

We want to reenact the channelRelativeUrl undefined case, for example we rename the channel's name, but it did has a certain value.

**So we are asking that in what kind of cases will app fail to get the channelRelativeUrl which is an undefined?**

Comment: We are unable to repro the scenario. Could you please share the repro steps ,so we can tried it from our end? and could you please confirm issue is with android ,web or desktop app?

Comment: Let me confirm that

Comment: Did you get chance to check?

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT Yes we are waiting for the report

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft Thanks for your reply, we are trying to figure out on what time this case would be happened.